# Letter writing: sample Italian formal letters

Tags: resources, formal

Does anybody know of some sample letters written in Italian?
Any online source would be greatly appreciated.
E.g. letters to estate agents/lawyers, etc.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE, @Andre!

Comment: Estate agents and lawyers who can't read English aren't worth their salt. You should be looking up opera libretti instead, it's much more constructive, not to mention a lot of fun.

Answer (score 5):

You can look at [this link](http://www.zanichellibenvenuti.it/wordpress/?p=3596) from Zanichelli or at [this one](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/lettere-commerciali-e-ufficiali-prontuario_(Enciclopedia_dell'Italiano)/). The first one is easier to understand for a non-Italian, the second is a bit more difficult IMHO.

If you aren't able to translate some part of these links ask in a comment and I will help you! (For your letter: Remember that English people say "you" for a formal communication, but in Italian is very informal say "tu").